# Adding custom font file locations in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, fonts, truetype

I need to use some proprietary fonts, and linux by default scans the following directory for font files.  However, in my environment, I don't have write access to these locations.

> /usr/share/fonts
>
> home/.fonts

I am looking at the following two workarounds for this but have had no luck so far.

1. Can I explicitly load a font file into the Linux font cache?
2. Can I add a custom font location to the list of scanned folders so it's picked up when I run `fa-cache -fv,` in case there is an XML config file I can add my custom paths to?

Comment: Assume you have access to /home/[your-user-name]/. Please try with a hidden folder `/home/[your-user-name]/.fonts/`. And just copy the new fonts into `.fonts/`, and restart the application in question.

Comment: In production my application would be running under a impersonated prod Id. Hence I won't have write access to that home directory as well